# R Use duplicated() with multiple columns of numeric and string data to ID not remove

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I cannot find a good way to do this, it is probably very simple.

I would like to include multiple variables/columns within the first part of the duplicated() function, aka ID dupes across multiple columns.

Example data are:

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
place =c('blue','green','blue',
'pink','pink','black','brown','green','blue'))
```

I want to ID the dupes with either TRUE/FALSE or 1/0. In the example data, a dupe flag should be produced for combo ID=1 / place = blue , and ID=2 / place = pink.

I have tried things like below, they do not work.

```
eg_data$dupes <- duplicated(eg_data$ID, eg_data$place)
eg_data$dupes <- duplicated(eg_data$ID & eg_data$place)
eg_data$dupes <- duplicated(eg_data$ID + eg_data$place)
eg_data$dupes <- duplicated((eg_data$ID, eg_data$place), incomparables = 
FALSE)
```

I do not want to select them into a new df, remove them from the existing DF, I just want to create a column that is the result of duplicated. I have looked at distinct(), unique(), but they do not do what I need, and I cannot get duplicated to work with more than one variable, or a combination of numeric and character data.

Sorry if this is some 101 stuff, but I can't find an easy way. I am pretty sure regex can do this, but I am not familiar with regex and would prefer something from base or dplyr or the like IE where I'm not just copy + paste a line of code that I do not understand and cannot replicate myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check multiple columns, you have to pass the entire data frame. So, for example, `duplicated(eg_data)` will check all columns and return `TRUE` if the entire row is the same as another row. If you want to check a subset of columns, then you'd want to subset the data frame; something like `duplicated(eg_data[, c('var1', 'var2', 'var4')])`. Here's the output:

```
> duplicated(eg_data)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This is not wanted to see, but what I expected to see. Thank you for your answer all the same, it confirmed that duplicated() can't handle this sort of thing w/o some massaging. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the duplicated() function *will* work on multiple columns, provided they are in sequential order within the dataframe.

In this EG above it would be, simply

```
eg_data$dupes <- duplicated(eg_data[,(1:2)])
```

By reordering the columns such that those you want to use to id dupes are columns 1:x, the syntax above will successfully produce a T/F column (or it did for me, using this data, and a larger dataset). Then just put the columns back into their original order.

I hope this helps others, it was pretty confusing to me at first.

Comment: What issue were you having if the columns were in a different order? What I mean is, can you give some examples of where you expected it to remove a row, but it didnt?